# Ubuntu docker daemon sets default policy as drop breaks networkmanager "shared to other computers feature" until a reboot

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, docker

**About**
I am currently running ubuntu 22.04 running Network Manager: version 1.36

I am looking to share my wifi interface which is connected to the internet with the device connected on eth0 ethernet port of my laptop,

I have used the network manager GUI to configure the eth0 to say `share with other computers`. as below
[image]

When I connect a raspberry pi to the ethernet port on my laptop, the raspberry pi was given  an ip address of 10.42.0.x and I am able to ping my laptop from the pi, But I am unable to reach the internet from pi.

**MY setup:**
internet <----->wlan0_laptop_eth0 <------> eth1_Rasberry pi
Note: I would like to share the internet on wlan0 of my laptop with the device connected on ethernet port(eth0) of my laptop.

**Issue:**
If I connect the pi after the laptop is completely booted up, I am unable to reach internet from the pi, pi still got an ip address in the range 10.42.0.x

**Current workaround:**
If I reboot my laptop with pi **already** connected to the ethernet port of my laptop then somehow I am able to reach internet from my PI

I looked at the ip tables, route, route metrics, I did not see anything out of place, I am happy to provide any logs if needed.

On ubuntu 21.04 I did not have this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issues seems to be the default FORWARD policy is set to drop by the docker daemon,

When I changed the default filter table FORWARD policy to accept, I am able to ping without the need to re-boot by laptop

**Fix for the Issue:**
Change the net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 in /etc/sysctl.conf explicitly, so that docker will not touch the forward policy as stated [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/14041#issuecomment-220044954). Note: If the file is not edited, docker daemon will set the forward policy to drop.

**Root cause:**
Its not the ubuntu version 22.04 rather its the docker daemon setting the forward policy to drop on start as documented [here](https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/#docker-on-a-router:%7E:text=Docker%20also%20sets%20the%20policy%20for%20the%20FORWARD%20chain%20to%20DROP).